# No longer reacting after moving a text

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

I changed my text today from a normal text to a variable in order to have access to localization for multiple language
Now, when the text is displayed it no longer also react with the emote and i have no clue why, because i only changed the text

Old code:

```
                if (!store.inQuiz) {
                message.channel.send("Processing audio, when it's done you can use !seek [timestamp]")
                    .then(function (message) {
                        new ffmpeg({
                                source: (ytdl(currentSongObj.link, {
                                    highWaterMark: 1 << 25,
                                    filter: 'audioonly',
                                    quality: 'lowestaudio'
                                })),
                                nolog: true
                            })
                            .on('end', () => {
                                try {
                                    store.statusProc = true;
                                } catch {}
                                message.react('✅')
                            })
                            .on('error', (err) => {
                                console.log('an FFMPEG error happened: ' + err.message);
                                skipSong(THIS_)
                                return;
                            })
                            .saveToFile('./root/DiscordMusicGiveawayBotNew/music/' + message.guild.id + '.mp3');
                    })
            }
```

Vs new code:

```
            if (!store.inQuiz) {
                getLanguageMessage(message.guild.id, "audioProcess").then((returnedText) => {
                    message.channel.send(returnedText);
                })
                    .then(function (message) {
                        new ffmpeg({
                                source: (ytdl(currentSongObj.link, {
                                    highWaterMark: 1 << 25,
                                    filter: 'audioonly',
                                    quality: 'lowestaudio'
                                })),
                                nolog: true
                            })
                            .on('end', () => {
                                try {
                                    store.statusProc = true;
                                } catch {}
                                message.react('✅')
                            })
                            .on('error', (err) => {
                                console.log('an FFMPEG error happened: ' + err.message);
                                skipSong(THIS_)
                                return;
                            })
                            .saveToFile('./root/DiscordMusicGiveawayBotNew/music/' + message.guild.id + '.mp3');
                    })
            }
```

What i did wrong and why right now it does no longe react also at message

Comment: add `return` in 3rd line

Answer (score 0):

`getLanguageMessage` should return `message.channel.send`

So simply remove the curly brackets

```
getLanguageMessage(message.guild.id, "audioProcess").then((returnedText) => message.channel.send(returnedText))
```

The full code should be

```
if (!store.inQuiz) {                 
    getLanguageMessage(message.guild.id, "audioProcess").then((returnedText) => message.channel.send(returnedText))
                .then(function (message) {
                    new ffmpeg({
                            source: (ytdl(currentSongObj.link, {
                                highWaterMark: 1 << 25,
                                filter: 'audioonly',
                                quality: 'lowestaudio'
                            })),
                            nolog: true
                        })
                        .on('end', () => {
                            try {
                                store.statusProc = true;
                            } catch {}
                            message.react('✅')
                        })
                        .on('error', (err) => {
                            console.log('an FFMPEG error happened: ' + err.message);
                            skipSong(THIS_)
                            return;
                        })
                        .saveToFile('./root/DiscordMusicGiveawayBotNew/music/' + message.guild.id + '.mp3');
                })
        }
```

Comment: It return the text, but also it's supposed to react at message after song was processed. For example this is before https://i.imgur.com/DsLHHDR.png and now it does no longer react to message after processing is done, it only return de text, but without react https://i.imgur.com/JpCTOg8.png

Comment: Did you try to edit the code as I told you?

Comment: Yes, i did. I also used your code and still same

Comment: it's strange, to solve you could also insert all the code inside the `then`of the `getLanguageMessage`function